# Invantive Control Excel formula shows path to another user and doesn't evaluate to correct balance value

Tags: invantive-control, exact-online

When I create myself a spreadsheet with Invantive Control, I can use formulas like I_EOL_BAL_YEAR_OPEN to get the balance year opening of some Exact Online company. When I reopen the spreadsheet, the balance is nicely calculated.

However, when a co-worker opens my spreadsheet over Google Drive, it displays as formula:

```
'c:\users\NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\AddIns\Invantive Control functions.xlam'!I_EOL_BAL_YEAR_OPEN(...)
```

It does not evaluate to a value.

He can manually replace all the paths, but that is not practical.

Is there a better way to make sure that the spreadsheet works at my co-worker's PC identical to what I get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally Invantive Control (or actually Excel) should display a window like the following when you open a spreadsheet that refers to a XLAM not reachable:

[image: update references in Dutch]

Something in English like: "A number of reference in your workbook can not be updated."

And then Invantive Control should automatically correct all references and show as such a confirmation window.

When it somehow doesn't happen, you can also go to Data ribbon and then to References:

[image: Relink references]

You can also use the Invantive tool for it:

[image: Relink references from Invantive Control ribbon]